# Concepts impose the 2nd argument is of type int

Tags: c++, c++20

As the title suggest, I want `foo` to only accept `int` type as it's 2nd parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename U, typename T>  concept IS_INT =
requires (U u, T t) {
        { t + 0 } -> std::same_as<int>;
};


IS_INT {U, T}
void foo (U u, T t)
{
        std::cout << "IS INT!" << std::endl;
        return;
}


int main()
{
        foo(1, 1);
        return 0;
}
```

It is working but g++ (version 10.2.0) is generating this warning

```
test.cpp:11:8: warning: template-introductions are not part of C++20 concepts [-fconcepts-ts]
   11 | IS_INT {U, T}
      | ~~~~~~~^~~~~~
```

Alternative way to write `IS_INT {U, T}` ? to get rid of this warning?

---

Last, how to re-write this constraint (t is int) without having to add 0?

```
    { t + 0 } -> std::same_as<int>;
```

---

**EDIT**:

```
template <typename U, typename T>  concept IS_INT =
requires (U u, T t) {
        std::same_as<T, int>;
};
```

Is not giving compilation error for

```
foo(1, "TTT");
```

Comment: `IS_INT {U, T}` What is that syntax? `{ t + 0 }` You want the promoted type to be `int`, or the type to be `int`?

Comment: @KamilCuk https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/constraints

Comment: Then you want `std::same_as<T, int>`, not `t + 0` to be `int`. `+` operator will promote it's operands.

Comment: @KamilCuk yes, but if I change the body `{ t + 0 } -> std::same_as<int>;` to `std::same_as<T, int>;` in main for `foo(1, "TTT")` I don't get compilation error. I guess I am misusing concepts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the binary form even in current core concepts version:

```cpp
template <typename U, typename T>  concept IS_INT =
requires (U u, T t) {
        { t + 0 } -> std::same_as<int>;
};


template<class T, IS_INT<T> U>
void foo (U u, T t)
{
        std::cout << "IS INT!" << std::endl;
        return;
}
```

(note the inversed parameter order: as a rule, if a concept accepts several parameters then only the first one is special, and U comes first in your definition). The full TS sugar, as g++ warns, is not currently standard.

> Last, how to re-write this constraint (t is int) without having to add 0?

```cpp
template<class T, class U> concept is_int = std::same_as<T, int>;
```

?

Comment: Oh, changing `{ t + 0 } -> std::same_as<int>;` to `std::same_as<T, int>;` this simple... and `template<class T, IS_INT<T> U>` is what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed by changing `{ t + 0 } -> std::same_as<int>;` to `std::same_as<T, int>;` will not give error for `foo(1, "TTT")` whereas `{ t + 0 } -> std::same_as<int>;` does. Am I missing something?

Comment: @TonyTannous yes. One is a nested requirement that needs to be satisfied, the other is but a single expression that compiles in any case and does not really constraint anything.

Answer (score 2):

> As the title suggest, I want foo to only accept `int` type as its 2nd parameter.

This is asking for a *unary* concept - you want to constrain the 2nd parameter, by itself, to be `int`. This is checking a requirement of a single type.

This:

```cpp
template <typename U, typename T>  concept IS_INT =
```

is a binary concept (Regardless of what follows the `=`). This is constraining two different types, `T` and `U`, in some way. No matter what you write after this, it doesn't actually address your use-case.

What you want to say is that a type is an `int`. That is:

```cpp
template <typename T> concept is_int = std::is_same_v<T, int>;
```

Which you can use, thusly:

```cpp
template <typename U, is_int T>
void foo (U u, T t);
```

This has no constraints on the first parameter, and the second parameter must be of type `int`.

---

Now, the standard library actually comes with a concept for exactly this problem. It's called [`same_as`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/same_as):

```cpp
template <typename U, std::same_as<int> T>
void foo (U u, T t);
```

---

Also, it's worth noting the requirement:

```cpp
{ t + 0 } -> std::same_as<int>;
```

Does not actually require `t` to have type `int`. This holds for any integer type below `int` as well, due to integer promotion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (already +1) I guess I am confused on when to use the requires and impose constraints in `{}` block. Thanks again.